# Problem: Assigning a group number to elements near eachother where groups are separated from spaces

Tags: c++

We have a room divided of 6x5 possible seats, every place in the 6x5 matrix could be a seat or could be empty.

We have the Matrix with all the seats already assigned on their location, and every seat has an unique code which is the actual Column(A,B,C,D,E)Row(1,2,3,4,5,6) position.

Unique code Example could be: A1, C4, E2, ....

The request is to assign the same group to all the seats that are next to each other:

Example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASler.png)

In this example the result is marked by the red color showing 3 groups.

The groups are assigned from 1 to N where the first top left will always be the first group.

There's no limitation on what to use; Arrays, Matrix, Lists, Trees, Graphs.

I would like to know if somebody here can find an efficient algorithm to execute the exercise on any seats configuration.

Comment: That's a very open-ended question. What have you tried?

Comment: This is a variation of the "Number of islands in a graph" problem.  Please do a search for that.

Comment: You should have seats and groups as separate objects and use pointers in both directions between them. Each seat knows its group and each group knows its seats. Then you go over the room and search, whether two different groups touch. If you find such groups, merge them to one group and update every involved seat. Then repeat until no two different groups touch.

Comment: Please inline images and give correct titles instead of putting links into the question.

Comment: I've tried recoursive functions to madness. So far the only thing which slightly worked was an iterative for 6x5 with a recoursive search right and search down from the x,y point you are, And continue until you find seats. Once you don't, return the smallest group found or generate a new one, in case of no other group was found, and assign all from that. Tho it doesn't work everytime as expected and I feel like is a bad way to solve the problem, due to incredibly long cycles and crazy complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical neighbourhood-search scenario. See [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) / [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithms.

You can instantiate the graph as a simple array or a two-dimensional array and have implicit edges between each two neighbouring cells that both have a seat assigned.

For example:

```
std::array<std::array<std::optional<unsigned>,7>,8> matrix;
```

As you can see, the matrix is two columns and two rows too large. If you leave these cells as sentinels you can save a lot performance. You implement a function that identifies all neighbours of a particular cell and use that to drive your BFS / DFS. You can initialise all cells containing seats to `0` and empty cells are automatically initialised to `std::nullopt`.

---

If you want to be slightly lazy and you have a very dense matrix, you could conceivably also go for [union find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).